# Strong Induction Number Theory

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction

I am having trouble using strong induction with the following problem:

Show that for any fixed positive integer $n$, the sequence, $2,2^{2}, 2^{2^{2}}, 2^{2^{2^{2}}},...$ is eventually constant modulo n.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @saulspatz really I have just tried several small cases and know that it suffices to show that the sequence is eventually constant mod φ(n).

Comment: You don't need induction to prove this assertion.

Comment: Is the sequence given by $x_{n+1}=2^{x_n}, x_0=2$?

Comment: @lhf yeah sorry i forgot to put 2^2. You are right